# Relativistic Kill Vehicle

Tags: special-relativity, collision

What would happen if a significantly supra-molecular object (say ranking from grams to low kilotons) would be accelerated to relativistic speeds (>.10 c) such that its worldline would intersect with a planetary surface?

Obviously, it would be a highly energetic event, more so with more mass and speed. But I'm not clear on whether any portion of the object **would make it to the surface and generate a crater, or simply blow up in the stratosphere and generate a tremendous shockwave** in the atmosphere? What combination of size and speed would be required to have long term planetary consequences for an Earth-type world (i.e. I'm thinking significantly more than a gentle hot wind)?

Most importantly, would a simple thin layer of gas say a few hundred million miles away be an effective defense? If not that, would anything we can feasibly imagine building?

For the purpose of I will ignore the consideration of how the impactor mass would reach this speed. Magical wand.

Comment: Added bonus question -- at what point would it be more energetic than detonating an anti-matter device of the same weight?

Comment: The bonus is easy - rest mass energy is doubled when $p^2c^2 = m_0^2c^4$, so when the momentum $p = m_0 c$. Now $p=\gamma m_0 v$, so $v=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Except you don't need to carry the regular matter mass, right?

Comment: The kinetic energy of the conventional matter is more than the rest mass of the antimatter at the velocity calculated. Not sure what you mean by "don't need to carry".

Comment: The m in the E=mc^2 in matter-antimatter anihillation is, if you assume 100% conversion, 2x(mass_antimatter), since it take a regular particle to annihilate each anti-matter particle.

Comment: ah yes - the kinetic energy needed is twice as big as I first estimated, and $v = \sqrt{\frac23}c$

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://what-if.xkcd.com/1

Comment: Hi Serban Tanasa. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a direct hit - so traveling through about 50 km of atmosphere - at 0.1 c that would take about 2 ms if it didn't get slowed down too much by the atmosphere.

What about drag force? Let's assume a radius $r$, density $\rho$, mass $m = \frac43 \pi r^3 \rho$. If it is a sphere, it experiences a drag force $F=\frac12 \rho_a v^2 C_d A$. Putting $\rho_a=1 kg / m^3$ (a bit low at the surface of the earth, a bit high at 50 km), C_d = 0.47 (sphere), we find a force for a 10 cm radius object of

$$F = 0.5\cdot 1 \cdot (3\cdot 10^7)^2 \cdot 0.47 \cdot \pi \cdot 0.1^2=6.6\cdot 10^{12}N$$

That velocity squared term is a real killer...

The power dissipation at that velocity is

$$P = F v = 2\cdot 10^{20} W$$

While the kinetic energy is

$$KE = \frac12 m v^2 = \frac12 \frac43 \pi r^3 \rho v^2 = 15 TJ$$

This suggests you need to be more careful with the math - solve the equation of motion (which will have some mad deceleration). But if you just imagined that you used all that power to heat a column of air 50 km long and 0.5 m radius (that's about how far the shock wave travels in 2 ms) the temperature / pressure rise would be very substantial. Mass of air in that column roughly 8000 kg, with a heat capacity of about 1 kJ / kg / K, means that 15 TJ is enough to heat the air to 150,000 K which will give rise to quite a good pressure wave - but one that will dissipate quickly as you get further from the "column of fire".

Still - this sounds like something that earth might survive. But it would make quite a mess.

Comment: The drag at those speeds isn't well treated by a viscous parameterization like that. The forces are essentially all inertial.

Comment: @dmckee - you are right. Can you do the math? Still - it will be a very violent event.